# Renaming Database Field Names for Different Customers

Tags: sql-server, web-applications

This is an odd sort of question and I'm not sure if it's appropriate for StackOverFlow or not so apologies if its not.

I have an application I'm building where I need to take into account for customers to have the ability to change the field name of a particular column within the application. For example changing FirstName to GivenName or ForeName. Basically the customer has the ability to change the display name of a field to whatever they like.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: You don't allow them to change the column name, you allow them to change the text that will be displayed for the column. You kind of alluded to that in your post but wanted to be sure. Your question is extremely broad to say the least. The way to handle this would be to store the column display name in a table. Of if this is .net you could store the value in a resx file.

Comment: With Sean on this.  However, another option for consideration is Synonyms

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I am missing how synonyms would help here. Not saying they wouldn't, I am just not getting it. I guess if the users are writing their own queries that would certainly work, but that sounds scary!!!

Comment: I have seen this done before with a 'translations' table, where you can store multiple names for the same thing, and based on the users preferences, it picks out the 'translation'.

Comment: @SeanLange You're right.  It was not a complete thought.  Retracting.

Comment: Thanks guys, the method Sean mentioned was what I was thinking of doing. I just wondered what others did to handle these type of situations.